# What to change ScrollBar color tied to a div element

Tags: html, css

I created a div that contains `overflow-y: scroll;` but now I am trying to change that scrollbar colour without effecting the browsers scrollbar colour.

```css
.details{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
    grid-gap:4rem;
    
}

.ben-details,.lucy-details,.castle-details,.brett-details,.sheldon-details{
    background-color: #421803;
    height:10rem;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}



.ben-details h6,.lucy-details h6,.castle-details h6,.brett-details h6,.sheldon-details h6{
text-align: center;
color: #421803;
font-size: 12px;
}

.ben-details p,.lucy-details p,.castle-details p,.brett-details p,.sheldon-details p{
    text-align: justify;
    color: #B99C7E;
    font-size: 10px;
    max-width: 6rem;
    
}
```

```html
 <div class="details">

        <div class="ben-details">
        <h6>Marketing Leading</h6>
          <p>With 5 years experience in marketing, 
            Ben does a great job of marketing our brand</p>
        </div>

        
        <div class="lucy-details">
          <h6>Head of HR</h6>
          <p>Lucy is the head of HR, she works with the company and the 
            employees to retain existing employees and hiring new talent.</p>
        </div>

        
        <div class="castle-details">
          <h6>Sales Lead</h6>
          <p>Castle is our lead Sales and his core values are building a 
            respectful and trusting relationships with our clients.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="brett-details">
          <h6>CEO</h6>
          <p>Brett built this company from the ground up and is proud of where it is today.
            He works with the company to help accomplish the company goals. He believes good 
            leaders step up and work along with thier employees.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sheldon-details">
          <h6>Front-End Developer</h6>
          <p>Sheldon is a talented Front-End Developer who works with the Marketing lead to
            keep our beautiful website up to date with our current and new products.
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
```

I did try `scrollbar-color:#B99C7E` under the following div classes:

- ben-details
- lucy-details
- castle-details
- brett-details
- sheldon-details

But no luck. I know ::-webkit-scrollbar will change the browser scrollbar, but not what I am looking for.

I have attached a screenshot,for some reason its disabling that scrollbar-color on the console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

scrollbar-color has two parts: thumb color an track color

e.g. scrollbar-color: black grey

This would make the background grey and the thumb on the scroll black.

Comment: unfortunetly, I tried that with the ```.ben-details``` for example. its not working